# SSH into EC2 with dynamic public IP address

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ip, hostname, ssh-keys

Typically I set ssh aliases as follows:

`ssh -i ~/path/key.pem ubuntu@public-host-name.compute-x.amazonaws.com`

But with EC2 instances, the `public-host-name` changes whenever an instance is stopped and restarted.

My EC2 instances are on a VPN and have constant private IPs.  What strategy can I use so that I can log into my instances without constantly changing the alias?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Private IP** is not accessible from outside the AWS network and is only useful when you have a cluster of EC2 instances for communication between them with-in your security group.

You could assign a [Elastic IP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) to the instance or use a [Dynamic DNS Solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS).

Comment: Elastic IPs are limited to 5 and unfortunately we have more instances than that. But +1 for anyone who doesn't need as many as we do.

Comment: well you could create a cronjob to run on boot that does one of these commands then output the current hostname/ip

`code` curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4

To get the public DNS hostname, you can change that to:
`code`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname

You can get the private IP for the instance, too:
`code`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4

Comment: @Emile - You can request more EIPs if you need them.

Comment: @Ethan - Many dynamic DNS solutions require the installation of a small client on your host machine, which serves to "report" back to the DynDNS service what the new dynamic IP address has been assigned or updated to the machine that is supposed to resolve to the network alias.

Comment: @richard-pascual I am very aware of that and since this is a EC2 instance it can be done very simply to accomplish the end goal.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a [Dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) solution for this.

You could use a DNS provider or configure your own Dynamic DNS server (there are [a](https://www.google.com/search?q=microsoft%20dns%20dynamic%20updates) [lot](https://www.google.com/search?q=bind9%20dynamic%20updates) of tutorials for this). There are also scripts for using [Route53](https://www.google.com/search?q=route53%20dynamic%20dns) for this.

Comment: Thanks for this answer +1. I don't have access to the DNS controls yet. But I'll try this if I do. I was hoping that I could use one elastic IP to connect to one instance and connect to the internal IPs via that one -- but that's beyond me.